# WebClient - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, webclient

Opening a public page from browser works fine.

Downloading same page using WebClient throws - (403) Forbidden.

What is going on here ?

Here is quick copy/paste example (used on console app) to specific page on web:

```
try
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    string content = webClient.DownloadString("http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%90");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: how often are you calling this url?  you could be throttled.

Comment: Not much I think, few times from browsers before trying with webclient. I have been downloading other pages from same site much more by now and they work fine every time. So it looks like this page only is throwing error?!

Comment: The page may be looking at the user agent header, and bouncing you because you don't provide one.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I've just tried it with Fiddler running to see the response and it returns the following notice with the status code.

> Scripts should use an informative
>   User-Agent string with contact
>   information, or they may be IP-blocked
>   without notice.

This works.

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");

    string content = webClient.DownloadString("http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%90");
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it didn't solve it for me, but you got me on a track. As a word of warning to those that follow, check your own security implementation first. I had forgotten to grant my user the rights to perform downloads and was receiving (correctly) a 403 message. Nothing to do with the IIS server, the client, the user-agent or anything.

Comment: @TheSenator thanks, in my case it was IIS IP address restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the server, you are trying to access is set up to use improved TLS protocol.
Make sure to add this to Global.asax.cs

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```