# C# How To Fix System.Net.WebException 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: c#, webclient

When I Try My Code It Gives Me `System.Net.WebExpection 403 Forbidden` Error.

.

Im Using This Code:

`string gettext = new System.Net.WebClient() { Proxy = null }.DownloadString("https://hastebin.com/raw/dawugajuvo");`

I Already Looked [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794260/webclient-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden) But Code Didnt Accept Special Characters Like: Ö, Ç, Ğ, Ü, Æ, Ş

How Can I Fix It?

Comment: Have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54893881/1154094

Comment: @the.Doc  Can You Please Read My Question Carefully? I Said `I Already Looked This Link But Code Didnt Accept Special Characters Like: Ö, Ç, Ğ, Ü, Æ, Ş`

Comment: The answer I linked to (regarding ServicePointManager) doesn't reference any special characters, and neither does your question (not directly anyway). You've provided a single URL which works in a browser and no other information.